# Error when Dapper Bulk. "You must explicity set the Provider"

Tags: c#, firebird, dapper-plus

I'm making a synchronization application, from Firebird to SQL Server.
And I'm using BulkInsert from Dapper Plus.

```
var fbClient = new FirebirdConnect();
using (var source = fbClient.GetConnection())
{

    if (source.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        source.Open();

    var sqlClient = new AzureConnect();
    using (var target = sqlClient.GetConnection())
    {
        if (target.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            target.Open();

        var lastUpdate = connection.Query<DateTime>($"select coalesce((select max(DateSyncTarget) from {metadados.TargetName}), getdate()-10000) LastUpdate").ToList();

        var resultSource = source.Query<MyClass>("select * from MyClass");

        target.BulkInsert(resultSource.Where(w => w.Data > lastUpdate[0]));

        var resultTargert = target.Query<MyClassSource>("select * from MyClass")

        source.BulkInsert(resultTargert.Where(w => w.Data > lastUpdate[0]));//Error here

    }
}
```

Everything happens well when I consult the source to do the insertion in the target.

But when I query on target to insert into source, it is giving the following error:

> The Provider could not be resolved. You must explicity set the
>   Provider.

Some idea of ​​what causes the error?

EDITED:

Full stack:

```
   em ..(BulkOperation )
   em ..(BulkOperation )
   em Z.BulkOperations.BulkOperation.BulkInsert()
   em Z.Dapper.Plus.DapperPlusAction.Execute()
   em Z.Dapper.Plus.DapperPlusAction..ctor(BaseDapperPlusActionSet action, String key, DapperPlusActionKind kind, Object dataSource)
   em Z.Dapper.Plus.DapperPlusActionSet`1.AddAction(String mapperKey, DapperPlusActionKind actionKind, TEntity item)
   em Z.Dapper.Plus.DapperPlusActionSet`1.DapperPlusActionSetBuilder(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction, String mapperKey, DapperPlusActionKind actionKind, TEntity item, Func`2[] selectors)
   em Z.Dapper.Plus.DapperPlusExtensions.BulkInsert[T](IDbConnection connection, String mapperKey, T item, Func`2[] selectors)
   em Z.Dapper.Plus.DapperPlusExtensions.BulkInsert[T](IDbConnection connection, T item, Func`2[] selectors)
   em Project.Plugins.Utils.Extensions.CommandExtensions.InsertSource[T](IDbConnection connection, IEnumerable result) na D:\Projetos\Project-API-Cloud\project-etl\Project.Plugins.Utils\Extensions\CommandExtensions.cs:linha 52
   em Autorizacoes.ERP.LIBSENHA.JobAutorizacoes.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) na D:\Projetos\Project-API-Cloud\Project-etl\Autorizacoes\JobAutorizacoes.cs:linha 105
```

Comment: Have you switched the terms source and target, usually you'd insert into the target, not the source. In any case, please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I Edited the question and include the full stack. @MarkRotteveel .I want to insert data from target to source, some time my user can insert in target and see it in source.

Comment: You haven't included the head of the stacktrace (which contains the exception name + message

Comment: The StackTrace is returning just this. http://imgur.com/a/fw1AZ

Comment: isn't there a scroller on the right ? try right-click and in menu "Select All" then rightclick again and in menu "Copy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Dapper Plus](http://dapper-plus.net/)

**Problem**

The following error is thrown by  Dapper Plus library:

> The Provider could not be resolved. You must explicity set the
>   Provider.

**Cause**

Dapper Plus cannot find the provider from the connection provided.

For example, the connection is probably something like an AzureConnection.

```
var sqlClient = new AzureConnect();
var target = sqlClient.GetConnection()
var fullName = target.GetType().FullName;
```

The library currently doesn't know it has to handle this connection in the same way as a SqlConnection.

**Solution #1 - SqlConnection Direct**

Use directly a SqlConnection instead.

If the current connection is only a wrapper, you may find the SqlConnection under sometimes a property named `UnderlyingConnection` or `InnerConnection`.

**Solution #2 - Report Issue**

I recommend you to open an issue [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Dapper-Plus/issues)

And provide information about how to use/what to download so we can use the same code as you for `AzureConnect`.

We usually fix this kind of issue within a few days.